# Format and replace timestamp column using awk

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I have multiple columns with following format

```
D,"4/2/2017 2:45:56 PM",ee,"4/2/2017 2:45:56 PM"
D,"03/02/2017 03:47:16 PM",ee,"03/02/2017 03:47:16 PM"
D,"09/2/2017 6:05:54 AM",ee,"09/2/2017 6:05:54 AM"
D,"5/01/2017 8:29:46 PM",ee,"5/01/2017 8:29:46 PM"
D,"4/2/2017 02:3:26 AM",ee,"4/2/2017 02:3:26 AM"
```

I want to format them as follows

```
D,"04/02/2017 02:45:56 PM",ee,"04/02/2017 02:45:56 PM"
D,"03/02/2017 03:47:16 PM",ee,"03/02/2017 03:47:16 PM"
D,"09/02/2017 06:05:54 AM",ee,"09/02/2017 06:05:54 AM"
D,"05/01/2017 08:29:46 PM",ee,"05/01/2017 08:29:46 PM"
D,"04/02/2017 02:03:26 AM",ee,"04/02/2017 02:03:26 AM"
```

I tried separating the column using awk -F"[,/ :]"and then processing based on lengths

but when there are multiple columns it becomes tedious.

Please suggest if there are any date-time or timestamp formatting options in awk so that i can process column-wise which would be fast

Answer (score 4):

```
$ cat tst.awk
function fmt(t,    f) {
    split(t,f,/["\/ :]/)
    return sprintf("\"%02d/%02d/%04d %02d:%02d:%02d %s\"",f[2],f[3],f[4],f[5],f[6],f[7],f[8])
}
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
{ $2=fmt($2); $4=fmt($4); print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
D,"04/02/2017 02:45:56 PM",ee,"04/02/2017 02:45:56 PM"
D,"03/02/2017 03:47:16 PM",ee,"03/02/2017 03:47:16 PM"
D,"09/02/2017 06:05:54 AM",ee,"09/02/2017 06:05:54 AM"
D,"05/01/2017 08:29:46 PM",ee,"05/01/2017 08:29:46 PM"
D,"04/02/2017 02:03:26 AM",ee,"04/02/2017 02:03:26 AM"
```

Comment: Best of both worlds.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use `awk` and its `printf` to format output:

```
awk -F '["/ :]' '{printf "%s\"%.2d/%.2d/%d %.2d:%.2d:%.2d %s\"%s\"%.2d/%.2d/%d %.2d:%.2d:%.2d %s\"\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16}' file
```

Output:

```
D,"04/02/2017 02:45:56 PM",ee,"04/02/2017 02:45:56 PM"
D,"03/02/2017 03:47:16 PM",ee,"03/02/2017 03:47:16 PM"
D,"09/02/2017 06:05:54 AM",ee,"09/02/2017 06:05:54 AM"
D,"05/01/2017 08:29:46 PM",ee,"05/01/2017 08:29:46 PM"
D,"04/02/2017 02:03:26 AM",ee,"04/02/2017 02:03:26 AM"
```

Comment: I prefer this approach because it works with mawk too (the default awk in Debian based distributions).  I was trying something with gensub() but gave up because it is not available in mawk.

Comment: @EdMorton My version is 1.3.3-17 shipped with Ubuntu 16.04.  This is the same version shipped with the recent Ubuntu 17.04 and the upcoming Debian 9.

Comment: In their webpage they state: "As noted, mawk has been neglected by some packagers".  I really never understood why Debian chose mawk as default awk, and don't even care to use the latest version.  I can understand the choice for /bin/sh not being /bin/bash, but not this.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk (`split` with `seps`). Code:

```
function doit(str,    b) {                      # b is a local var buffer
    gsub(/\"/,"",str);                          # remove quotes
    n=split(str,a,"[/ :]",seps);                # split on special chars
    for(j=1;j<=n;j++) {                         # loop all elements in a
        if(a[j]~/^[0-9]+$/)                     # process all number elements
            a[j]=sprintf("%02d", a[j]) seps[j]; # zeropad
        b=b a[j]                                # gather buffer
    }
    return "\"" b "\""                          # return quoted
}
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
{
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2)                         # loop the right ones
        $i=doit($i)                             # call the contractor
}
1
```

Run it:

```
$ awk -f program.awk file
```

Output:

```
D,"04/02/2017 02:45:56 PM",ee,"04/02/2017 02:45:56 PM"
D,"03/02/2017 03:47:16 PM",ee,"03/02/2017 03:47:16 PM"
D,"09/02/2017 06:05:54 AM",ee,"09/02/2017 06:05:54 AM"
D,"05/01/2017 08:29:46 PM",ee,"05/01/2017 08:29:46 PM"
D,"04/02/2017 02:03:26 AM",ee,"04/02/2017 02:03:26 AM"
```

Comment: got an error .. 4 is invalid number of arguments for split

Comment: It is for GNU awk, sir. I believe you mentioned mawk in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` as well, to replace all single digits between word boundary to pad with `0`. But it will change any single digit in your data, even if it is not in the dates column. So use it **only** if you want to replace all single occurrence of digits appended with `0`

```
sed 's|\b\([[:digit:]]\)\b|0\1|g'
```

Use `-i` with sed if you want to make the change permanent.

> How it works.

The regex `\b\([[:digit:]]\)\b` will match single digits between word boundaries, captured with `(braces)`. Now in `replace` part of `sed`, hardcoding `0` with first matching patter `\1` will give you `0` padded with single digits.

> Regex Demo

To see how this regex works see **[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ni8x8x/2)**

> Working example:

```
bash-4.2$ cat file1
D,"4/2/2017 2:45:56 PM",ee,"4/2/2017 2:45:56 PM"
D,"03/02/2017 03:47:16 PM",ee,"03/02/2017 03:47:16 PM"
D,"09/2/2017 6:05:54 AM",ee,"09/2/2017 6:05:54 AM"
D,"5/01/2017 8:29:46 PM",ee,"5/01/2017 8:29:46 PM"
D,"4/2/2017 02:3:26 AM",ee,"4/2/2017 02:3:26 AM"

bash-4.2$ sed -i 's|\b\([[:digit:]]\)\b|0\1|g' file1

bash-4.2$ cat file1
D,"04/02/2017 02:45:56 PM",ee,"04/02/2017 02:45:56 PM"
D,"03/02/2017 03:47:16 PM",ee,"03/02/2017 03:47:16 PM"
D,"09/02/2017 06:05:54 AM",ee,"09/02/2017 06:05:54 AM"
D,"05/01/2017 08:29:46 PM",ee,"05/01/2017 08:29:46 PM"
D,"04/02/2017 02:03:26 AM",ee,"04/02/2017 02:03:26 AM"
```